# A piece of fabric 2D to mesh 3D

Tags: animation

I have a piece of fabric with a specific silhouette shape, envision its UV map in 2D view. I would like to animate the fabric to sew and wrap it around the body with a specific movement. I want to connect specific stitching points from the open fabric to the sewn garment. I would like to understand if I can make the Hook, Sewing, and Follow Path tools interact. I have the 3D model of the fabric in CLO3D, both in its sewn and extended versions. The traditional sewing method typically works with two fabric pieces, side A and side B, but I only have a single piece of fabric.

Comment: Welcome! Just a quick question to help us narrow down the issue, what have you tried so far? This site is usually for if you’ve tried one thing or another and have found an issue with it rather than asking for how to do x y or z. Please elaborate on what you’ve tried so far and what luck you’ve had. Cheers :)

Comment: A sketch or screenshot would also help. How complex is the model and the fabric that you want to wrap around the model? The short answer to your question is: yes, you can use hooks, pin groups, sewing, shape keys, force fields and even an armature to control and influence a cloth simulation. If the fabric mesh is too heavy (geometry-wise) you also can use a low-poly proxy model and bind the fabric with a Mesh/Surface Deform modifier.